# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function set_magic_quotes_runtime() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla_1.5.15\installation\includes\framework.php

Tags: php, xampp, joomla1.5, htdocs

I am getting the above error while installing joomla 1.5.15...

And the code inside **framework.php** file is

```
 @set_magic_quotes_runtime( 0 );

 @ini_set('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode', '0');
```

Please help what i want to do to run joomla in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a *seriously* outdated version of Joomla, which contains many security flaws.
I strongly recommend [downloading the latest Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/download.html) instead!

As for why you're getting the error: The "magic quotes" functionality has been removed from PHP, due to many reasons. One of which it completely failing to do what it was designed for, namely keeping things secure.

Comment: Thank you So there is no way to install joomla 1.5 version

Comment: There is always a way, but it would require either downgrading your PHP install or modifying Joomla itself. Neither of which are recommended, and will leave you with known security flaws wide open for abuse. With Joomla as popular as it is, we're talking mere hours before said flaw will be found and exploited. With the end result of a nefarious third party having full control over your server.